# Open extension instead of GNOME volume OSD

Tags: gnome

I'm using [better volume indicator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/759/better-volume-indicator/) extension and it shows volume like this on scrolling on sound icon:

[image: better volume indicator]

I want to have that volume indicator instead of GNOME volume OSD.

How can I do that?